# Using ProviderBundle from gwtplatform to bundle together non-presenter classes

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-platform

For presenters, we can use @ProxyCodeSplitBundle to bundle the presenters in a ProviderBundle implementation.

How can we bundle the non-presenter classes together in a ProviderBundle?

Answer (score 0):

As far of I know, any class that is injected into your Presenter using  `@ProxyCodeSplitBundle` annotation will be bundled with it. I don't think you can bundle classes unrelated to a Presenter.

Comment: When we generate compiler report, we get several non-presenter classes in initial download segment. We want to bundle them together and then put behind the split point. Is there any alternate approach to do that?